# unset matching values in two arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I'm wondering if there is an easier way to do what is demonstrated in the following code.  The goal of this code is to identify the high, low, medium values that come from the $fat_values array.  The code is functioning properly as written, but I'm hoping there is a more concise way to identify the medium fat value.

A word about the data - the values are allowed to have 2 values the same, though sometimes all 3 values will be unique.  When 2 values are the same, one is to be shown as high fat and the other as medium fat.  When 2 values are the same, the third value is always 0 (that is enforced by a validation rule that's not shown here).

```
#---test with unique values---
$fat_values = array(7, 0, 4);
// $fat_values = array(7, 4, 0);

#---test with 2 values the same---
// $fat_values = array(0, 40, 40);
// $fat_values = array(40, 40, 0);

#calculations
$fat_low = min($fat_values);
$fat_high = max($fat_values);

$lowhigh = array($fat_low, $fat_high);

//loop through $fat_values - if element matches one in $lowhigh array remove it from $fat_values and from $lowhigh arrays; this will leave 1 element in $fat_values at the end

foreach ($fat_values as $key => $value):
if (in_array($value, $lowhigh)):
    unset($fat_values[$key]);
    foreach ($lowhigh as $k => $v):
        if ($k = array_search($value, $lowhigh)):
            unset($lowhigh[$k]);
        endif;
    endforeach;
endif;
endforeach;

//for remaining element in $fat_values[key], key can be 0 or 1 or 2 so copy value to a new variable to eliminate dealing with key
foreach ($fat_values as $key=>$value):
    $a = $value;
endforeach;

$fat_medium = $a;

#display results
echo "<pre>" . print_r($fat_values,1) . "</pre>";
echo 'high ' . $fat_high . '<br>';
echo 'low ' . $fat_low . '<br>';
echo 'medium ' . $fat_medium . '<br>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$fat_low = min($fat_values); // get the lowest
$fat_high = max($fat_values); // get the highest
$fat_mid = array_uniq($fat_values); // set mid wchich we gonna filter and make array unique (no doubles)

// array_search gives the key of matching the value for low
unset( $fat_mid[ array_search($fat_low, $fat_mid) ]);
// array_search gives the key of matching the value for high
unset( $fat_mid[ array_search($fat_high, $fat_mid) ]); 

if (count($fat_mid)===0){ $fat_mid = 0;} // no left, give it 0
else{ $fat_mid = current($fat_mid); }// get frist (and remaining) value
```

Comment: Is there a ] missing in each unset statement?  If so, where does it belong?

Comment: fixed it, it were the unset lines

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = array(6, 5, 5);
$cnt = array_count_values($arr);
$keys = array('fat_high', 'fat_medium', 'fat_low');
if (count($cnt) < 3){
    $cnt = array_flip($cnt);
    ksort($cnt);
    $arr = array(end($cnt), end($cnt), 0);
} else {
    rsort($arr);
}
$arr = array_combine($keys, $arr);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [fat_high] => 5
    [fat_medium] => 5
    [fat_low] => 0
)
```